# Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed) Android In App

Tags: android

I am using Google Play Billing Library to sell a In App product.I have only one managed product.During testing I bought this product as a test order, every thing was working fine.But I have deleted the Apps from the Play Store and forgot to consumed the product.Then I have created a new application and replaced the new public key.But when I am querying to inventory I am getting this error.

Its happening only to that particular phone.

kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing package name will solved the issue.